# Pandas: multiply row with constant based on row index

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
Time           00:00  ...     23:00
Date                  ...          
2022-08-01  0.000000  ...  0.249884
2022-08-02  0.177274  ...  0.846479
2022-08-03  0.275984  ...  0.333089
2022-08-04  0.206237  ...  0.295780
2022-08-05  0.138474  ...  0.163897
...
```

how can I multiply row values depending from the date (index column)? For example - for the range from August 1 to 3 - by 2; for the range from August 4 till the last row in dataframe - by 3.
should I follow solutions like here:
[link to the article on slackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-do-i-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample code to multiply the values in a range:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10,2)),
              columns=["col1", "col2"],
              index=pd.date_range("20221212", periods=10))
```

[image: Dataframe before change]

Now to multiply from 12th to 16th by 2 and the rest of rows by 3:

```
for col in df.columns.values:
    df.loc['2022-12-12' :'2022-12-16',col] *= 2 
    df.loc['2022-12-17' :'2022-12-21',col] *= 3
```

[image: Dataframe after changes]

Comment: doing     print (df['2022-12-08':'2022-12-10']['Date'] *2 )
I get raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'Date' (there are data for the indicated dates)

Comment: print (df.index.name) gives Date; print(df.columns.tolist()) gives ['00:00', '01:00', '02:00', '03:00', '04:00', '05:00', '06:00', '07:00', '08:00', '09:00', '10:00', '11:00', '12:00', '13:00', '14:00', '15:00', '16:00', '17:00', '18:00', '19:00', '20:00', '21:00', '22:00', '23:00']

Comment: To multiply each column, use: 

for col in df.columns.tolist():
    df['2022-12-08' :'2022-12-10'][col]*=2

Comment: following advice I get: Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  for col in df.columns.tolist(): df['2022-12-08' :'2022-12-10'][col]*=2

Comment: I updated the code to avoid the slice warning.

Comment: Many thanks! I like Pandas more and more :)